# Browser extension popup that executes a function

Tags: javascript, function, popup, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a simple firefox extension. It includes a popup with a button (#showList), which I would like to use to execute a function (addListBorders()). This function adds borders to list elements on the page.

What is the proper way to execute this function?

```
var ext = false;
var $ulList = document.querySelectorAll('ul')
var $olList = document.querySelectorAll('ol')
var $dlList = document.querySelectorAll('dl')

function addListBorders() {
    if (ext == false) { 

        for (let $ul of $ulList) {
            $ul.style.border = "5px solid pink"
        }
        for (let $ol of $olList) {
            $ol.style.border = "5px solid pink"
        }
        for (let $dl of $dlList) {
            $dl.style.border = "5px solid hotpink"
        }

        ext = true

    } else { 

        for (let $ul of $ulList) {
            $ul.style.border = "none"
        }
        for (let $ol of $olList) {
            $ol.style.border = "none"
        }
        for (let $dl of $dlList) {
            $dl.style.border = "none"
        }

        ext = false
    }
} 

 //browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(addListBorders);

const $button = document.getElementById('showList')
const CSS = "body { border: 20px solid red; }";

$button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.style.color = 'red'
     browser.tabs.insertCSS({code: CSS});

     browser.runtime.addListener(addListBorders);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Here it is for others reference:

```
$button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     browser.tabs.executeScript({code: 'addListBorders()'});
})
```